# What is the SetViewController in IOS

Tags: ios

What is the SetViewController in IOS which case developer preferred?

what is difference between  setViewController and PushViewController  in IOS?

Please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First thing it is not `SetViewController` but it is `setViewControllers` because it's sets `array of view controller`.

You can only set view controller to `navigation controller` or `tabbar controller` like wise you can `pushviewcontroller` only in `navigation controller` not in `tabbar controller`

Now lets understand the concept of `navigation stack` :

For example you have one navigation controller says it `nav`.

It hasn't any objects (View controllers).

Now for example you have array of three view controllers like `A,B & C` and you set that array to you `navigation controller` something like,

```
  [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllerArr];
```

Then your navigation stack become like

`A -> B -> C (top of stack)`

Now you push one view controller to same navigation stack, let's say it `D` something like,

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:D animated:YES];
```

Then your navigation stack like become,

`A -> B -> C -> D (top of stack)`

Now if you pop one view controller something like,

```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then it pop top of stack and then your stack looks something like,

```
 `A -> B -> C (top of stack)`
```

Again pop one then,

```
 `A -> B  (top of stack)`
```

So, basically main difference between set and push view controller is, when you set view controllers, you are setting array means multiple array. So, we can say that `setViewController` is initialization of navigation controller with initial controller (initialization of navigation stack)

where push or pop is adding or removing view controller to or from navigation stack.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

A navigation controller is used to manage a stack of view controllers. You can "push" controllers onto the stack one at a time (this is what you would do almost all of the time) or you can "set" a stack containing multiple controllers in one go. [Read the manual.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)